# Delete all tags matching a pattern (local and remote)

Tags: git, tags, git-tag

I have accumulated a lot of junk tags in my repositories. I want to delete all tags matching a given pattern, but not ALL tags, just those that match.

What is the best way to do this?

I'm on Windows (but I do have git-bash available if it is easier to do in a linux like way.. for instance I was thinking maybe xargs might be the way???)

is git for-each-ref the way to go here? I can't quite puzzle out how to use it though.

Note, I want to do this both for my local repo and for the origin.

---

For example, I do not want any tags that start with "someTag" as these were early tests. List with a pattern finds them, but delete with the same pattern fails

```
C:\ado\Info_11713_Test_Project>git tag -l someTag*
someTag-${Build.BuildNumber}
someTag-20230303.10
someTag-20230303.8
someTag-20230303.9
someTag-20230306.1
someTag-20230308.6
someTag-20230308.7
someTag-20230308.8
someTag-20230308.9

C:\ado\Info_11713_Test_Project>git tag -d someTag*
error: tag 'someTag*' not found.
```

Update: in git-bash I was able to do this which got rid of the local tags

```
HBIUSERS+H034561@W10DC2C2IC123 MINGW64 ~/lp/ado/Info_11713_Test_Project (main)
$ git tag -d `git tag -l | grep someTag-2`
Deleted tag 'someTag-20230303.10' (was a7142a6)
Deleted tag 'someTag-20230303.8' (was 2b27bab)
Deleted tag 'someTag-20230303.9' (was 2ac9c9a)
Deleted tag 'someTag-20230306.1' (was c05dd94)
Deleted tag 'someTag-20230306.2' (was 719b2b7)
Deleted tag 'someTag-20230306.3' (was 8aa2287)
Deleted tag 'someTag-20230306.4' (was df7bbfd)
Deleted tag 'someTag-20230308.2' (was fd54536)
Deleted tag 'someTag-20230308.3' (was 00ade5b)
Deleted tag 'someTag-20230308.4' (was 62f2166)
Deleted tag 'someTag-20230308.5' (was 916a394)
Deleted tag 'someTag-20230308.6' (was 93d43b3)
Deleted tag 'someTag-20230308.7' (was a85f46d)
Deleted tag 'someTag-20230308.8' (was 8af7d1f)
Deleted tag 'someTag-20230308.9' (was 71dd321)
```

but it didn't work for origin:

```
HBIUSERS+H034561@W10DC2C2IC123 MINGW64 ~/lp/ado/Info_11713_Test_Project (main)
$ git push --delete origin  `git tag -l | grep someTag-2`
fatal: --delete doesn't make sense without any refs
```

Edit: xargs can do it. but it's really slow... is there a faster way?

for local:

```
 git tag -l someTag-2* | xargs -I '{}' git tag -d '{}'
```

for remote:

```
git tag -l SomeTag-2* | xargs -I '{}' git push --delete origin '{}'
```

Comment: Your first command removed all local tags so when you ran `git tag -l SomeTag-2*` for the second time it produced no output. You should have done these commands in reverse order but the advice is too late. So my advice is to restore tags from remote using `git fetch --tags origin` and rerun your commands in reverse order — 1st remove tags on `origin`, after that on local. Also you can try [`git push --prune origin`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---prune) but that's a rather dangerous command.

Comment: You could use `git ls-remote --tags` to list the existing tags in the remote repository.